# Iterating over numpy array, np.ndindex making a mess

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a dataframe and since I have to perform many calculations on it I figured I'd give Numpy a try, so I'm just learning how to use it.
This is my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n'], 'col2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n'], 'col2': [100, 212, 300, 405, 552, 641]})
df['col3'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()
df1['col3'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()

df2 = df.merge(df1, on='col1', how='outer')
```

Now what i want to do is append `col2_y - col2_x - sum(col3_y)` to column `col3_y`
**if** `col2_y != col2_x`. now I tried this

```
df2 = df2.to_numpy()
    df = [df2[x, 3:4] - df2[x, 1:2] for x in np.ndindex(len(df2))]
    df2 = [np.where(df2[x, 1:2] != df2[x, 3:4],
                              np.append(df2[x, 4:5], (df2[x, 3:4] - df2[x, 1:2]) - (df2[x, 4:5].sum())),
                              df2[x, 4:5]) for x in np.ndindex(len(df2))]
```

but somehow from this

```
[['z' 100 list([]) 100 list([])]
 ['x' 200 list([]) 212 list([])]
 ['c' 300 list([]) 300 list([])]
 ['v' 400 list([]) 405 list([])]
 ['b' 500 list([]) 552 list([])]
 ['n' 600 list([]) 641 list([])]]
```

It's turning into this

```
[array([[0]], dtype=object), 
 array([[12]],dtype=object),
 array([[0]],dtype=object),
 array([[5]], dtype=object), 
 array([[52]], dtype=object), 
 array([[41]], dtype=object)]

[array([[list([])]], dtype=object), 
 array([[list([])]], dtype=object), 
 array([[list([])]], dtype=object), 
 array([[list([])]], dtype=object), 
 array([[list([])]], dtype=object), 
 array([[list([])]], dtype=object)]
```

Am I not using the `np.ndindex` correctly? Is the slicing correct at least?

Do I even need it or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: This definitely feels too complicated. It's not totally clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you make a simpler example, without all the `np.empty` and `df.merge` business at the beginning? It looks like all you want to do is compute a new column from existing columns, based on some condition — you're not going to need NumPy for that.

Comment: @kwinkunks unltimately my goal is to make many different intense time sensitive computations based on the available data but in this case I'm trying to append the number to a list inside of the column for each row and for some reason pandas acts unpredictably when I'm trying to do it and for some numbers it appends 0, some of them it adds ``+`` to the list and some are appended just as needed

Comment: Okay, but the mixture of `pandas` and `numpy`, with dataframes, lists and arrays is making it hard to see what you're trying to do, for me anyway. Pandas already uses NumPy internally to acheive things like elementwise operations — I'm really not sure you need to add a NumPy layer here.

Comment: `np.ndindex(len(df2))` is no better than `range(len(df2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataframe:

```
In [43]: df2
Out[43]: 
  col1  col2_x col3_x  col2_y col3_y
0    z     100     []     100     []
1    x     200     []     212     []
2    c     300     []     300     []
3    v     400     []     405     []
4    b     500     []     552     []
5    n     600     []     641     []
```

and the array derived from it (note the object dtype):

```
In [44]: arr = df2.to_numpy()
In [45]: arr
Out[45]: 
array([['z', 100, list([]), 100, list([])],
       ['x', 200, list([]), 212, list([])],
       ['c', 300, list([]), 300, list([])],
       ['v', 400, list([]), 405, list([])],
       ['b', 500, list([]), 552, list([])],
       ['n', 600, list([]), 641, list([])]], dtype=object)
```

That iterative difference - the result is actually a list:

```
In [46]: arr1 = [arr[x, 3:4] - arr[x, 1:2] for x in np.ndindex(len(arr))]
In [47]: arr1
Out[47]: 
[array([[0]], dtype=object),
 array([[12]], dtype=object),
 array([[0]], dtype=object),
 array([[5]], dtype=object),
 array([[52]], dtype=object),
 array([[41]], dtype=object)]
```

The same thing as Series:

```
In [48]: df2['col2_y']-df2['col2_x']
Out[48]: 
0     0
1    12
2     0
3     5
4    52
5    41
dtype: int64
```

and array column different, without iteration.  Object dtype math is still slower than numeric:

```
In [50]: arr[:,3]-arr[:,1]
Out[50]: array([0, 12, 0, 5, 52, 41], dtype=object)
```

A numpy integer dtype version:

```
In [51]: df2['col2_y'].to_numpy()-df2['col2_x'].to_numpy()
Out[51]: array([ 0, 12,  0,  5, 52, 41])
```

I'm not sure I want to tackle the following line

```
[np.where(df2[x, 1:2] != df2[x, 3:4],
                              np.append(df2[x, 4:5], (df2[x, 3:4] - df2[x, 1:2]) - (df2[x, 4:5].sum())),
                              df2[x, 4:5]) for x in np.ndindex(len(df2))]
```

It can be cleaned up with:

```
[np.where(x[1] != x[3],
          np.append(x[4], (x[3] - x[1]) - sum(x[4])),
          x[4]) 
 for x in arr]
```

Since all the `x[4]` columns are empty lists this

```
[array([], dtype=float64),
 ...
 array([], dtype=float64)]
```

oops, somewhere in fiddling I've added values to the last lists:

```
In [65]: df2
Out[65]: 
  col1  col2_x col3_x  col2_y col3_y
0    z     100     []     100    [0]
1    x     200     []     212   [12]
2    c     300     []     300    [0]
3    v     400     []     405    [5]
4    b     500     []     552   [52]
5    n     600     []     641   [41]
```

Comment: This example will certainly help me understand the subject better! Thanks for your effort, I appreciate yout help! p.s.( just noticed the condition I had... thanks for pointing it out, rookie mistake)